# Disable default response massages SpringDoc Open API 3

Tags: swagger, openapi, springdoc

I want to migrate from SpringFox library to SpringDoc in order to generate API docs in Open API v3 format.
In my SpringFox configuration, I have disabled default response messages:

```
@Bean
public Docket publicApi(ServletContext servletContext) {
    Docket docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        ...
        .useDefaultResponseMessages(false);
```

But I can't find a way to do it in SpringDoc. [Migration guide](https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox) says "remove Docket and use `application.properties` instead". But there is no such property.

SpringFox version - 2.9.2 and SpringDoc version - 1.5.2

Is it possible to disable default response messages in SpringDoc?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to disable responses described in @ControllerAdvice you should add

```
springdoc.override-with-generic-response=false
```

to .properties file

By default, it's set to "true" which automatically adds @ControllerAdvice responses to all generated responses.
You can find it in [docs](https://springdoc.org/properties.html)

Thanks a lot to [bnasslahsen](https://github.com/bnasslahsen) for answering my questions on [springdoc github](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1123)